# What is the best way to design solution to my multiple mutable reference issue?

Tags: rust

I've been working on a Rust implementation of the game Catan. I have a decent handle on *why* my code is not compiling, but I'm not experienced enough with the language to know that the best solution to my problem is.

Here is the code minus implementation details:

```
fn has_player_won(game: &Game, player: &Player) -> bool {
...
}

fn upkeep(player: &mut Player) {
...
}

fn take_turn(game: &mut Game) -> Option<Player> {
    let player = &mut game.players[game.current_player_index];
    upkeep(player);
    if has_player_won(game, player) {
        return Some(player.clone())
    }

    None
}
```

And my compiler error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*game` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
   --> src/main.rs:139:23
    |
137 |     let player = &mut game.players[game.current_player_index];
    |                       ------------ mutable borrow occurs here
138 |     upkeep(player);
139 |     if has_player_won(game, player) {
    |                       ^^^^  ------ mutable borrow later used here
    |                       |
    |                       immutable borrow occurs here
```

How should I go about resolving my current need to hold a mutable reference to the player and the game at the same time? Is there a better way to structure or think about this kind of situation? I think I can just pass the current_player_index around, but that feels inelegant.

I tried googling to find a similar problem or solution. Most of what I saw was explaining what mutable references are and why multiple can't exist at the same time. I'm trying to find something more tailored towards strategies for avoiding the issue I've gotten myself into. It seems I'm either not thinking about the problem the right way or structuring my code poorly. Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix is just to not hold a mutable reference to the `Player` since `has_player_won` doesn't need one:

```
fn take_turn(game: &mut Game) -> Option<Player> {
    upkeep(&mut game.players[game.current_player_index]);

    let player = &game.players[game.current_player_index];
    if has_player_won(game, player) {
        return Some(player.clone())
    }

    None
}
```

You could also modify the signature of `has_player_won` to take a player index instead of a `&Player`, which would also prevent passing a reference to one `Game`'s player to another `Game`.

I would also advise that many of these functions should probably be `&self`-receiving functions in an `impl Game {}` block, which would make their usage substantially simpler as well.

Comment: "_The simplest fix is just to not hold a mutable reference_": Agree, but also: Rust offers [shadowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/variable_bindings/scope.html).

Comment: @jsejcksn That won't help here, unless you mean rebinding `player` and letting NLL drop the mutable reference early, which is functionally the same as the code in my answer.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76087864/what-is-the-best-way-to-design-solution-to-my-multiple-mutable-reference-issue/76087903?noredirect=1#comment134188252_76087903) @cdhowie Yes, that's my meaning.